# Convert Arrays inside ArrayDeque to String

Tags: java, string, arraydeque

I am trying to return a string pulled from the 2nd element of a given array inside of an ArrayDeque

I tried casting it and toString and concatenation after ToArray but I get this... I need to return it as a String

"The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to String"

```
    ArrayDeque<String[]> bindings_and_var = new ArrayDeque();

public ArrayDeque<String[]> pushBindings(String var, String bindings) {
    //var first element, bindings 2nd
    String[] this_bindings_and_var = new String[2];

    bindings_and_var.addLast(this_bindings_and_var);
    return bindings_and_var;
}

public ArrayDeque<String[]> bindingsVal() {

    return bindings_and_var;
}

public String lookup(int index) {
    String[] array = (String[]) bindings_and_var.toArray();

     //PROBLEM AREA vvv
    String s = "" + array[index][1];


    return s;
```

Answer (score 0):

You have defined your Deque as String[] while when you are doing `bindings_and_var.toArray();` you would receive object array with each object as String array. Try,

```
    Object[] array = (String[]) bindings_and_var.toArray();

    Object obj = array[index];
    String[] myArray = (String[])obj; 
    String s = "" + myArray[1];
```

Or

```
    int i = 0;
    for (String[] s : bindings_and_var) {
        if (i == index) {
            return s[1];
        }
        i++;
    }
```

so that you don't have to iterate the whole collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your `lookup` method should look like this:

```
public String lookup(int index) 
{
    int counter = 0;
    for (Iterator<String[]> itr = bindings_and_var.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
    {
        String[] t = itr.next();

        if (counter == index)
        {
            return t[1];
        }

        counter++;
    }
}
```